# How can i load a webpage inside a tab through clicking the tab header?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a home page with multiple  tags. One of the  contains a link. If I click on the link, a new web page should load on one of the other  in home page. How do I do that?

More over, if the newly loaded page on one of the other  contains a link, and clicking on the link helps the 2nd new web page load in the  tag replacing the first content of the div , the question is how do I do that?

This is an assignment given to me and the rules are:

I need help and advice about how to do it.
Thanks for any help or suggestions regarding my question.

Comment: What have you tried yet ? as you already saying that this is an assignment.. I would suggest you first you should try from your end and then post your question if required... a little trial and error is always require.

Comment: well what im trying to do is when i clicked on the tab header, it will display a webpage in the tab content area but its displaying the web page on the page that im seeing. ive tried to used <a href="somecode.html" target="contentAreaofMyTab"> but its not giving the results that i want.

Answer (score 1):

You use `AJAX` to load the content inside the page

Check this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/fBrYp/1/

This can explain how to do.

Script

```
$('#nav li a').click(function(){

        var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #content';
        $('#content').hide('fast',loadContent);
        $('#load').remove();
        $('#wrapper').append('<span id="load">LOADING...</span>');
        $('#load').fadeIn('normal');
        window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-5);
        function loadContent() {
            $('#content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())
        }
        function showNewContent() {
            $('#content').show('normal',hideLoader());
        }
        function hideLoader() {
            $('#load').fadeOut('normal');
        }
        return false;

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are referring to is loading content using AJAX.

I would recommend reading the following documentation since there is quite a bit of information the goes into programming this.

http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/